# Python map object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does the following script give the error:

`payIntList[i] = payIntList[i] + 1000

TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable`

```
payList = []
numElements = 0

while True:
        payValue = raw_input("Enter the pay amount: ")
        numElements = numElements + 1
        payList.append(payValue)
        choice = raw_input("Do you wish to continue(y/n)?")
        if choice == 'n' or choice == 'N':
                         break

payIntList = map(int,payList)

for i in range(numElements):
         payIntList[i] = payIntList[i] + 1000
         print payIntList[i]
```

Comment: Are you using Python 3 ?

Comment: @user567797 - This works fine for me
@ Felix: He is not using python 3 as he is using print as a statement!

Comment: The whole thing below the while loop can be shortened to `payIntList = [int(x) + 1000 for x in payList]; print(*payIntList, sep='\n')` (or `for x in payIntList: print x` in Python 2.x where `print` isn't a function) without losing readability (arguably, it's even more readable).

Comment: @Guanidene: He is using Python 3, as he has map objects. But he is trying to run Python 2 code on it, hence the errors.

Comment: I'd like a "Why do I get errors when I run Python 2 code on Python 3" question, that we can mark all of these as duplicates to. ;)

Answer (score 180, accepted):

In Python 3, `map` returns an iterable object of type `map`, and not a subscriptible list, which would allow you to write `map[i]`. To force a list result, write

```
payIntList = list(map(int,payList))
```

However, in many cases, you can write out your code way nicer by not using indices. For example, with [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
payIntList = [pi + 1000 for pi in payList]
for pi in payIntList:
    print(pi)
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but ideally you would not be converting maps to lists for use cases such as this. Maps are already iterable, and appear to be an order of magnitude faster to iterate through compared to lists. So not only do you not need an index, you don't need a list at all. The cleaner code would be, since payIntList is already a map, `for i in payIntList: print(i + 1000)`

Answer (score 23):

`map()` doesn't return a list, it returns a `map` object.

You need to call `list(map)` if you want it to be a list again.

Even better,

```
from itertools import imap
payIntList = list(imap(int, payList))
```

Won't take up a bunch of memory creating an intermediate object, it will just pass the `ints` out as it creates them.

Also, you can do `if choice.lower() == 'n':` so you don't have to do it twice.

Python supports `+=`: you can do `payIntList[i] += 1000` and `numElements += 1` if you want.

If you really want to be tricky:

```
from itertools import count
for numElements in count(1):
    payList.append(raw_input("Enter the pay amount: "))
    if raw_input("Do you wish to continue(y/n)?").lower() == 'n':
         break
```

and / or

```
for payInt in payIntList:
    payInt += 1000
    print payInt
```

Also, four spaces is the standard indent amount in Python.

Comment: Well that is the case for python3, but here he seems to be using python2.x as he is using print as a statement.

Comment: Your code snippet *does* store all ints in memory in a list. Using iterators is indeed useful and saves memory, especially with multiple layers of transformations, but adding `list` around an iterator takes away that advantage!

Comment: When you do `list(map(...))` it creates a `map`, then creates a `list`, then deletes the `map`, so for a while both are in memory at once. When you do `list(imap(...))` this isn't the case. That's why I said "take up memory with an _intermediate_ object"

Comment: So you are assuming Python 2? Then `list(map(...))` is redundant, because - as the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) states, "the result [of `map`] is always a list".

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to use range for this problem in pypy3 or python3, so it is actually less code..

```
for i in payIntList: print ( i + 1000 )
```

and coincidentally matches RustyTom's comment in PhiHag's solution above. Note : Can not reference a map using array brackets [] in pypy3 or python3 or it will throw the same error.

```
payIntList[i]
```

Map ref caused the error.