# How to assign a value to each digit in a large number?

Tags: python, arrays

I was doing Problem 8 on Project Euler when I ran into a problem. I couldn't find a way to assign each digit in the thousand digit number its own value. Here is my code:

```
def Problem8():
    x = []
    num = [73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934969835203127745063262395783180169848018694788518438586156078911294949545950173795833195285320880551112540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557668966489504452445231617318564030987111217223831136222989342338030813533627661428280644448664523874930358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866701724271218839987979087922749219016997208880937765727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243525849077116705560136048395864467063244157221553975369781797784617406495514929086256932197846862248283972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474821663704844031998900088952434506585412275886668811642717147992444292823086346567481391912316282458178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450]
    def ans(i):
        one = num[i]
        two = num[i+1]
        three = num[i+2]
        four = num[i+3]
        return one*two*three*four
    for i in range(1,(len(num2)-3)):
        x.append(ans(i))
    print(x)

Problem8()
```

I was just checking if it would work for the four adjacent digits, not thirteen like the question said. But my array kept on coming up empty. Why is it doing that? Is there a better way?

Comment: There is one number in your num list, if you want to split it into digits you need to call str on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've written your code, doing `[<bignumber>]` creates a list with only *one* element, namely the big number in question. In that case, doing `num[i]` for `i > 1` results in nothing.

If you want to create a list with all the digits of the number, consider doing the following:

```
num = map(int, str(<bignumber>)) # creates a list of digits
```

The way this works is that `str` converts `bignumber` to a string, while `map` first converts the string iterable to a list of its individual characters  and then converts each character in that list back to an integer, so that you now have an array of digits.

The rest of your analysis can then work without issue.

---

Other issues:

- `num2` is undefined. It appears nowhere in your code, and should throw an error. I presume it was a typo.
- Your `i` only starts from 1, not 0 in your `range` call. Consider changing this `range(0, len(num) - 3)` so as not to avoid an off-by-one index error. Even better: use a list comprehension.
- In Python 2.7, `range` creates an actual list in memory with 1000 elements. For even larger numbers, this is going to be a massive chunk of memory. Consider doing `xrange` instead, or - if on Python 3 - do nothing.
- Lastly, you can compactify the whole output of `ans` into a single line. No need to create extra variables like `one`, `two`, etc.

Comment: Why the downvote? This works perfectly and goes beyond the bare minimum the OP requires.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I do have a suggestion.  `map()` requires an iterable for its second argument, but it doesn't need to be a list.  You can simply use `map(int, str(<bignumber>))`

Comment: You mean `str(bignumber)`? `bignumber` is an int, not iterable, and thus can't be used in `map`. :) But, yes, that's a good suggestion.

Comment: You caught me before I edited. ;)

Comment: @zondo Took your suggestions into account, edited my answer.

Comment: I did what you said, but an error pops up. It says "'map' object is not subscriptable" Why is this happening and what does it mean?

Comment: In Python 3, `map` returns a generator, not a list. Do `list(map(int,str(<bignumber>))`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800481/python-map-object-is-not-subscriptable) for advice.

Comment: This code worked great, but I want to know how to add a value to every two digit number. Meaning how would I do the sam thing except this time with two digits.