# Model of a Probability Distribution

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, spyder

I'm trying to run a `python` script that is used as an example on this data science site:
https://www.datascience.com/blog/introduction-to-bayesian-inference-learn-data-science-tutorials

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import factorial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16,7)

def likelihood(theta, n, x):
    """
    likelihood function for a binomial distribution

    n: [int] the number of experiments
    x: [int] the number of successes
    theta: [float] the proposed probability of success
    """
    return (factorial(n) / (factorial(x) * factorial(n - x))) \
            * (theta ** x) * ((1 - theta) ** (n - x))

# The number of impressions for our facebook-yellow-dress campaign
n_impressions = 10

# The number of clicks for our facebook-yellow-dress campaign
n_clicks = 7

# Observed click through rate
ctr = n_clicks / n_impressions

# 0 to 1, all possible click through rates
possible_theta_values = map(lambda x: x/100., range(100))

# Evaluate the likelihood function for possible click through rates
likelihoods = map(lambda theta: likelihood(theta, n, x)\
                                , possible_theta_values)

# Pick the best theta
mle = possible_theta_values[np.argmax(likelihoods)]

# Plot
f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(possible_theta_values, likelihoods)
ax.axvline(mle, linestyle = "--")
ax.set_xlabel("Theta")
ax.set_ylabel("Likelihood")
ax.grid()
ax.set_title("Likelihood of Theta for New Campaign")
plt.show()
```

I'm using Spyder. The errors that I am getting include:

```
    %matplotlib inline
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

as well as

```
mle = possible_theta_values[np.argmax(likelihoods)]
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable
```

and

```
likelihoods = list(map(lambda theta: likelihood(theta, ctr, x)\
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

I tried a solution that I found here:
[Python map object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800481/python-map-object-is-not-subscriptable)

```
# Evaluate the likelihood function for possible click through rates
likelihoods = list(map(lambda theta: likelihood(theta, n_clicks, ctr)\
                                , possible_theta_values))
```

But it gave the error

```
TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()
```

How can I fix the script to run in Spyder please?

Comment: `%matplotlib inline` is for enabling plots in JuPyter notebooks, Remove it for Spyder

Comment: The other problems sound like they might be a python 2/3 issue. Are you sure the version used for this script corresponds to the version you have?

Comment: I'm not sure of that J. I'm using Python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor modifications in the code to make it work. I had to convert your `map` iterable objects to lists to make your code work for the reasons you mentioned : `TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable`. I also had to define explicitly the `x` array to be able to use it while calculating `likelihoods`.

```
# 0 to 1, all possible click through rates
possible_theta_values = list(map(lambda x: x/100., range(100)))

n = n_impressions
x = n_clicks

# Evaluate the likelihood function for possible click through rates
likelihoods = list(map(lambda theta: likelihood(theta, n, x)\
                                , possible_theta_values))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm still getting "NameError: name 'n' is not defined"

Comment: Oh yes, I took `n = 5`. Just choose any number you want. I edited my answer

Comment: I found that if I use "n = n_impressions" and "x = n_clicks" then I get the same graph as on the data science site.