# In Python, why x = list(map(x)) is ok but x = map(x); x = list(x) causes error?

Tags: python

An example:

```py
y = [1, 0, 0, 1]
y = list(map(lambda i: [0, 1] if i == 1 else [1, 0], y))
print(y)
```

This runs correctly without error:

```
[[1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
```

However, if I assign the map object to a variable and THEN convert it to a list like this:

```py
y = [1, 0, 0, 1]
y = map(lambda i: [0, 1] if i == 1 else [1, 0], y)
y = list(y)
print(y)
```

It causes an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    y = list(y)
  File "...\test.py", line 2, in <lambda>
    y = map(lambda i: [0, 1] if i == 1 else [1, 0], y)
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable
```

What is the mechanism behind this? I am confused even though I do have some basic understandings of Python bytecodes and assembly.

Using Python 3.9.7.

Thank you all form stackoverflow! I did not expect such quick help before this post, which is my very first.

I think @Barmar 's detailed answer solves the problem, and @ThierryLathuille 's comment on the question briefly pointed out the core underlying mechanism for me. My sincere gratitude goes for both!

Comment: Already answered on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800481/python-map-object-is-not-subscriptable

Comment: `map` returns an iterator, so the lambda doesn't get executed until you pull elements from the iterator, which happens when you build the list. At this point, `y` doesn't refer to the list anymore, but to the `map` object.

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the y variable before the lambda runs.

Try this

```
y = [1, 0, 0, 1]
m = map(lambda i: [0, 1] if y[i] == 1 else [1, 0], y)
y = list(m)
```

Comment: BTW I don't think the code or the lambda makes much sense, but that's a separate problem.  The lambda should operate on elements of the list, and you're using elements of the list to index the global list (why?).

Comment: The list contains indexes.

Comment: Indexes into what?

Comment: Into the list itself.

Comment: Yeah, that's what doesn't make sense to me.  index 0 into y is 1, index 1 into y is 0.  lambda i: 0 if i else 1 (?)

Comment: It's toy code, probably created to demonstrate this problem.

Comment: @dirck It is not quite toy code but me really trying to convert an array of 0's and 1's to an array of one-hot vectors for my MLP code with this when processing the labels. xD

Comment: @CalmaKarma maybe `lambda i: [0, 1] if i==0 else [1, 0]` (?) Sorry, I can't figure it out.

Comment: @dirck Ah my foolish mistake! Didn't think too much about it. Thanks for pointing out! I will edit my post about this.

Comment: That's right! I did not know that map does not execute the function on an element of the iterables until the element is pulled. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using the same variable `y` for the map as the original list.

In the original code block, you don't reassign `y` until after `list()` has iterated over the list. So inside the `lambda`, `y` refers to the original list, and you can use `y[i]` to access those list elements.

But in the version where you assign the result of `map()` to the variable, `y[i]` in the `lambda` is trying to access the `map` object, not the original list. You get that error because the `map` object cannot be indexed, only iterated.

Comment: Thanks! The answer is really easy to understand combined with @ThierryLathuille 's comment on the question! Thanks again for your immediate comment and answer!